# Ошибка "segmentation fault" при вызове dlopen и запуске отладки, используя gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Я не очень силён с работой со встраиваемым системами. Но данный момент попал в некоторые замкнутый круг. Собрал python 2.7 (под linux'ом) для контроллера (судя по тому, что выдаёт `uname -a`, у него архитектура процессора i486). Python запускается, работает. Но при импорте библоитек которые требуют динамические библиотеки например:

```
import random
```

требует _random.so и т.д. появляется `segmentation fault`. Опытным путём я понял, что проблема с вызовом функции `dlopen` (я написал простенький helloworld), который падает в `segmentation fault` именно при вызове `dlopen`.

```
...
cout << "Opening libmyf.so...\n";
void* handle = dlopen("./libmyf.so", RTLD_LAZY);
...
```

Далее я пробую поставить gdb чтобы понять вообще в каком месте падает. Но тут возникает главная проблема: как собрать gdb. В интернете куча мануалов, я почти всё уже перепробовал. Либо не собирается gdb, либо собирается, запускается на контроллере, но сам падает в segmentation fault при начале отладки. Вопросы:

1. Если gdb запустился help, например, работает, а потом он сам выдает "segmentation fault" при старте отладки. Это может быть из-за того, что он как-то криво мной собран или нет?
2. Как вообще правильно собрать под linux gdb. Какие флаги мне указывать, какие нет? Кто вообще что может посоветовать в моей ситуации (кроме убитьсяобстену :) )?

Comment: Что значит "для контроллера"? т.е. uname -a кроме i486 что-нибудь говорит? (dlopen в системе для него вполне может и отсутствовать, а вот какой-нибудь отладчик с фронтендом gdb -- присутствовать.

Comment: говорит еще и версию ядра:  2.6.11. Вы про какой отладчик с фронтендом?

Comment: Ну я просто не понял слово "контроллер". Потому как в микроконтроллерах часто используется gdb, общающийся с сидящей в контроллере резидентной частью. У gdb для этого специальный протокол разработан.

Comment: да я пробовал и обычный gdb запускать и как gdbserver, падает на segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Варианты для дальнейших действий:

1. Сделать эмулятор (виртуалку, chroot) с этим окружением на нормальном компьютере, скопировав в него ядро и систему из встраиваемой системы. Если на эмуляторе всё заработает, то проблема может быть в инструкциях процессора;
2. Использовать strace, он проще. К динамическим библиотекам, правда, это имеет косвенное отношенение;
3. Использовать valgrind. Если он слишком тяжёлый, то использовать пункт "1.", увеличив количество памяти в эмуляторе; В valgrind'е также есть режим взаимодействия с gdb.
4. Использовать `LD_DEBUG=libs` `LD_DEBUG=symbols` и т.д. С этими переменными окружения динамический загрузчик должен выводить больше сообщений.